# Network Access via Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, virtualbox

I have a weird problem. Here is my configuration.

I installed VirtualBox on Windows 7 PC.

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on VirtualBox.

I installed many programs via terminal and I can still install. My browser can connect to internet.

But I cannot ping any website e.g. google.com. I cannot download anything from git.I can only ping 192.168.1.1 that is all.

What would be the reason guys?

**UPDATE**

I can ping with another internet connection which I use in office.

Comment: I assume your firewall on Windows is not blocking outgoing connections?

Comment: misleading title, probably better to ask this in virtualbox forum.  can you switch to a bridged network in virtualbox?

Comment: this question should be moved to somewhere like SuperUser

Comment: As I said above I can connect internet through web browser, even apt-get install works on terminal. But I cannot ping any website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my router was preventing it. I reset it and now using WEP instead of WPA2.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a valid nameserver. Check your network configuration and `/etc/resolv.conf`.